# How can I copy an installed wordpress project from a server to another one?

Tags: php, wordpress

There is an implemented/installed wordpress project on a server (which is working). Now I made a zip file from all its directories and files and copy/pasted it to another server (and extracted it). Also I created an export of the database and imported it to the new server.

Also I modified `wp-config.php` file and set the new `db-name`, `user-name`, `password` accordingly. But sadly when I open the new server it throws:

> Error establishing a database connection

Any idea what's the problem and how can I fix it?!

Comment: Have you thoroughly checked all database credentials? Is there any way to enhance logging?

Comment: @NicoHaase how can I check database credentials?

Comment: Well, have  a look at `wp-config.php` and try to login from a SSH shell on your server to the MySQL server with these credentials

Comment: You should know them when you created database. Also don't forget to change host address (if needed)

Comment: @Justinas When I create the database I have only the name of it. And when I create the user, I have both the user name and the password. And finally I will assign the database to the user. So I have `database-name`, `user-name`, `password`. Anything else do I need?

Comment: @NicoHaase will give it a try ..

Answer (score 0):

Use https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/ or https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/ to get as close to a clone as possible

Answer (score -1):

Your credentials are incorrect. As said in comments you need to try to connect manually to your database to check if they are correct. I had the same problem recently.

> So I have database-name, user-name, password. Anything else do I need?

You don't need anything else if they are correct.

If your url will not be the same you have to export your database. Open the `.sql` file with notepad. Find and replace `http://oldurl.com`to `http://newurl.com`